# Magento isn't showing new category name added programatically in admin

Tags: magento

I've just created a new root category programatically using this code:

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->setStoreId(0);
$category->setName('Storybloks6');
$category->setUrlKey('storyblocks6');
$category->setIsActive('1');
$category->setIncludeInMenu('0');
$category->setDescription('Produtos que aparecem em destaque no carrossel da home');
$category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
$category->setIsAnchor('0');
$category->setLevel('1');
$category->setParentId('1');

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('1');
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath()); 
$category->save();
```

The category is added, but in the admin category page, it labels doesn't appear on the menu:
[image: new category appears as (0) on menu]
New categ appeas as (0) on menu. How can I fix it?

Comment: by the way ... you should use `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');`

Comment: Hi @Alex, I tried this way. Same problem. When I go there and saves the (0) in admin form, it fixes. I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you viewing the category tree in the backend in the same store (admin store - code 0) or maybe another store where no label was set.

Comment: Yes, it was set for a different store. But neither changing to the correct one, it still doesnt work. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Create a file named somename.php in the Magento root folder and paste the following code into the file and save it. Just run the script through your webbrowser. It should create a category "Cars" -it worked for me on 1.4.2.0.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default'); // Default or your store view name.

//get a new category object
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setStoreId(0); // 0 = default/all store view. If you want to save data for a specific store view, replace 0 by Mage::app()->getStore()->getId().

//if update
if ($id) {
  $category->load($id);
}

$general['name'] = "Cars";
$general['path'] = "1/3"; // 1/3 is root catalog
$general['description'] = "Great new cars";
$general['meta_title'] = "Cars"; //Page title
$general['meta_keywords'] = "car, automobile";
$general['meta_description'] = "Some description to be found by meta search robots.";
$general['landing_page'] = ""; //has to be created in advance, here comes id
$general['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE"; //static block and the products are shown on the page
$general['is_active'] = 1;
$general['is_anchor'] = 0;
$general['url_key'] = "cars";//url to be used for this category's page by magento.
$general['image'] = "cars.jpg";


$category->addData($general);

try {
    $category->save();
    echo "Success! Id: ".$category->getId();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```